# Simple Number Counter using Ruby

Tags: ruby, numbers, counter

I'm a total beginner at ruby and coding in general and I was wondering if you guys could help me out. My brother and I are working on a simple ruby code that will be able to search tons of text files for certain numbers. At this moment we only have it able to search one text file at a time. Here's the code we have so far:

```
puts "Drag your file to this window and press ENTER"
file_path = gets.chomp
puts "\nWhat is your target number?"
target_number = gets.chomp

# This will output the number of occurrences of your target number
file_text = File.read(file_path)
count = file_text.scan(target_number).count
puts "\n\nCount: #{count}"

gets
```

My question is, how can I change this code so that it reads multiple text files at once rather than one at a time?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you missed to write your question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Dir.glob method.  For example:

```
files = Dir.glob('*.txt')
# => ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']
```

Then you can loop through them:

```
count = 0
for file in files
  file_text = File.read(file)
  count += file_text.scan(target_number).count
end
puts "\n\nCount: #{count}"
```

Good luck :)